# People API: FBS quota limit exceeded

Tags: api, google-api, grpc, quota

While syncing contacts using the People API, I've run into a quota limit error which I don't understand and haven't found any information about it on the net. The error is the following:

```
"error": {
"code": 429,
"message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
"status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.QuotaFailure",
    "violations": [
      {
        "subject": "QUOTA_EXCEEDED",
        "description": "FBS quota limit exceeded."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Does anyone have any idea what this error is related to ?

Thanks

Comment: If someone else has this issue: the problem might come in case you're performing too many calls in a short period of time. Waiting a few minutes will be enough to get it working again.

Comment: FYI, initially I could get rid of this issue by waiting for 10 minutes. But since 2 months I always get this error when making this call, and I cannot even add just 1 contact. I always get the error no matter the frequency of the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to create an answer from my comment, for future reference.

The error **429** indicates that you maybe violating the [google's terms of service](https://developers.google.com/terms/) (especially under d. API Limitations).  To quote it:

> d. API Limitations
>
> Google sets and enforces limits on your use of the APIs (e.g. limiting
>   the number of API requests that you may make or the number of users
>   you may serve), in our sole discretion. You agree to, and will not
>   attempt to circumvent, such limitations documented with each API. If
>   you would like to use any API beyond these limits, you must obtain
>   Google's express consent (and Google may decline such request or
>   condition acceptance on your agreement to additional terms and/or
>   charges for that use). To seek such approval, contact the relevant
>   Google API team for information (e.g. by using the Google developers
>   console).

When you made too many calls you were probably put on a blacklist, which expires in some time. The limit for [People API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/quotas).  You **need** to apply for higher quotas.

For example, [*Google Play Developer API*](http://developers.google.com/android-publisher/quotas) has a 200 000 calls per day, you have to request if you need more.

The google probably wants you to have a good reason to have more and also is protecting from the DDOS attacks.

Comment: Thanks @tukan, this is fair enough :)

Comment: I suspect that the number of write requests would also effect this.