# Rate limited with the response MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT

Tags: go, google-api, google-people-api, google-api-go-client

I am proto-typing an application using Google new People API. During my testing I have added and deleted contacts in batches, to see how many can be added per minute and per day in total.

I understand the documentation say how many can be added per minute, but from my testing I don't seem to get anywhere close to this. Even when reviewing my metrics, my request is far long than the supposed limits per minute and per day.

My main question I have is after a couple of attempts across a service account on 3 of my gmail account's I am now getting back `googleapi: Error 429: MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT, rateLimitExceeded`. I can't find any mention of `MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT` online. I assumed from the error it meant I have too many contacts, but when running a delete script it appears I don't have any at all.
This response is returned for all 3 accounts on my development machine now for longer than 24 hours, which is making me believe I have possibly been blocked and not rate limited?

Client code for running the test:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "google.golang.org/api/people/v1"
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "time"
    //"github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)


func chunks(xs []string, chunkSize int) [][]string {
    if len(xs) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    divided := make([][]string, (len(xs)+chunkSize-1)/chunkSize)
    prev := 0
    i := 0
    till := len(xs) - chunkSize
    for prev < till {
        next := prev + chunkSize
        divided[i] = xs[prev:next]
        prev = next
        i++
    }
    divided[i] = xs[prev:]
    return divided
}

func main(){
    
    ctx := context.Background()
    srv, err := people.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to create people Client %v", err)
    }
    

    file, err := os.Open("test125k.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed opening file: %s", err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
    var txtlines []string
 
    for scanner.Scan() {
        txtlines = append(txtlines, scanner.Text())
    }

    chunkEmails := chunks(txtlines,200)
    count := 0
    var validPeopleResources []string

    log.Printf("Started")

    for i,chunk := range chunkEmails{ //
        var contacts people.BatchCreateContactsRequest
        contacts.ReadMask = "emailAddresses,photos"
        for _,chunkEmail := range chunk{
            var contact people.ContactToCreate
            var person people.Person
            var personEmails people.EmailAddress
            personEmails.Value = chunkEmail
            var AllEmails  = [](*people.EmailAddress){
                &personEmails,
            }
    
            person.EmailAddresses = AllEmails
            contact.ContactPerson = &person
            contacts.Contacts = append(contacts.Contacts, &contact)
        }

        r,err := srv.People.BatchCreateContacts(&contacts).Do() 
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Unable to create contacts")
            log.Printf(err.Error())
            log.Fatalf("")
        }

        var contactEmail string
        
        var resource string
        for _, validPeople := range r.CreatedPeople {
            contactEmail = validPeople.Person.EmailAddresses[0].Value
            resource = validPeople.Person.ResourceName
            validPeopleResources = append(validPeopleResources,resource)
        }
        
        count = count + 1

        if count == 2 {
            var contactToDelete people.BatchDeleteContactsRequest 
            contactToDelete.ResourceNames = validPeopleResources
            _,err = srv.People.BatchDeleteContacts(&contactToDelete).Do()
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Unable to delete contacts")
                log.Printf(err.Error())
                log.Fatalf("")
            }
            validPeopleResources = nil
            count = 0
            log.Printf("performed delete")
        }


        log.Printf("%d comlpeted",i)
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: This might give you more context on why the error happened.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53846895/people-api-fbs-quota-limit-exceeded

Comment: @JasonE. Your link speaks about `RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED` but not `MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT`. What is the significance of `MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT`? It must have some specific meaning.

Answer (score 7):

"MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT" happens when you try to insert new contacts to the Google account, but they already have the maximum number of contacts.

The max limit is 25,000, since 2011: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2011/05/need-more-contacts-in-gmail-contacts.html

It should be noted here that Google also takes the deleted contacts into account for calculating the count. You can find the deleted contacts in the [Contacts Trash](https://contacts.google.com/trash). These contacts will be cleared after 30 days.